# How to order parent table field by child table updates

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i hope i wrote the title correctly. i just started django recently, and i have problem with queryset.

so i have these models, views and template file.

models.py

```
class Topic(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Room(models.Model):
host = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-updated', '-created']

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

views.py

```
def topics(request):
"""topics page for listed view of topics"""

room_count = Room.objects.all().count()
topics = Topic.objects.all()

context = {'topics': topics, 'room_count': room_count}
return render(request, 'base/topics.html', context)
```

topics.html

```
        {% for topic in topics %}
        <li>
          <a href="{% url 'home' %}?q={{topic.name}}">{{ topic.name }}<span> 
        {{topic.room_set.all.count}}</span></a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
```

this loop clearly sorts topics by its created time. but when there is a new room or if there is an update in any existing room, i want the topic related to that room to be at the top. how can I do this? I tried several attempts, but it doesn't solve the issue. Or should I change my database architecture? since I'm fairly new to databases, I'm having a headache to solve this issue. I've been googling for two or three days but I couldn't find a solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: what to you mean by "I want it to be sorted by new POST request in room field."  ?

Comment: sorry for my english. i mean when there is a new room or if there is an update in any existing room, i want the topic related to that room to be at the top.

Comment: ok so you want topics to be ordered by the newest related room (Room.updated) ? given the title i thought you want it to be sorted by the number of related rooms.

Comment: exactly. I have changed title.

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.objects.all().order_by("-id")
```

from latest to oldest

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by annotating a new colum and sort by it

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

#subquery which gets latest update from all rooms for the given topic
latest_room_update = Room.objects.filter(topic=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-updated')

topics = Topics.objects.all()
#add the new column
topics = topics.annotate(latest_related_room_update=Subquery(latest_room_update.values['updated'][:1))

#sort
topics = topics.order_by('-latest_related_room_update')
```

edit because .latest() in subquery seems to cause query execution and therefore result in failure

Comment: since im a newbie i don't exactly understand logic behind this but i copy paste your code (apart from typing error annoate) it doesn't work, i got an error 'This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.' now i will google this issue to fix it. thanks for help.

Comment: hm maybe it is because of latest function in the subquery  try and change  latest_room_update = Room.objects.filter(topic=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-updated') and than use slicing to get get the latest  -> Subquery(latest_room_update .values('updated')[:1]))